# Why is home being required in my url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a route defined

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NoRightsRoute",
    url: "norights",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "NoRights" }
);
```

and in a check on if the user has rights I redirect them to this route if they don't

```
Response.RedirectToRoute("NoRightsRoute");
```

the url that it redirects to is

```
https://localhost/norights
```

Home is removed which I would expect since that is assumed by MVC but I get an error

```
"The resource could not be found"
```

if I change the url to

```
https://localhost/Home/norights
```

the page loads correctly.  Why is "Home" being required in my url?  Is there some way to have "Home" included in the url so that the redirect works or get the page to load as it should when assumed?

Comment: Is there another route defined before that?

Comment: yes there are 3-4 other routes on that page.  could they be conflicting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to remove the default, and hard code Home in url.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NoRightsRoute",
    url: "Home/norights",
);
```

But check that other links /redirections are not impacted !

Comment: the first option put the source controller in the url.  The second option puts Home into the URL and the redirect now works.  thank you :)

Comment: @MattBodily just check that other routes / links  are not impacted also !

Comment: thank you for the warning.  Always good to be aware,  just ran through other pages and everything is working correctly.  thank you again